# how to send complex type via ksoap2-android to wcf service ? - how to configure wcf service?

Tags: android, database, wcf, android-ksoap2

I try to send a complex type via ksoap2-android to a wcf service.
Basicly I followed that guide http://seesharpgears.blogspot.de/2010/10/ksoap-android-web-service-tutorial-with.html
I was able to recieve a complex data type from the web service, but when I try to send one I get the following error:

```
a:DeserializationFailed
The formatter threw an exception while trying to deserialize the message: There was an error while trying to deserialize parameter http://tempuri.org/:es.
The InnerException message was 'Error in line 1 position 373. Element 'http://tempuri.org/:es' contains data from a type that maps to the name 'http://tempuri.org/:EventSeries'.
The deserializer has no knowledge of any type that maps to this name.
Consider using a DataContractResolver or add the type corresponding to 'EventSeries' to the list of known types - for example, by using the KnownTypeAttribute attribute or by adding it to the list of known types passed to DataContractSerializer.'. 
Please see InnerException for more details.
```

The question is how can I solve this ? The error is returned in the envelope.
As I did everything as described in the tutorial and receieving complex types work, I think the error is produced on the server side, but unfortunatelly I don't know anything about wcf services. What must I change on the wcf service to get it work ?

We tried something like

```
[ServiceKnownType(typeof(EventSeries))]
```

as described in the error message but it didn't help

The Method on the web service looks like that

```
public int InsertEventSeriesForAndroidVIntES(EventSeries es)
    {
    ...
    }
```

I attach my android code, just in case I screwed something up.

```
SoapObject request = new SoapObject("http://tempuri.org/, "InsertEventSeriesForAndroidVIntES");

        EventSeries es = new EventSeries(10, "call Test");


        PropertyInfo propertyInfo = new PropertyInfo();

        propertyInfo.setName("es");
        propertyInfo.setNamespace("http://tempuri.org");
        propertyInfo.setValue(es);
        propertyInfo.setType(EventSeries.class);

        request.addProperty(propertyInfo);

        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        envelope.dotNet = true;

        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

        envelope.addMapping(request.getNamespace(), "EventSeries", EventSeries.class);

        HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
        androidHttpTransport.call("http://tempuri.org/IDiversityService/InsertEventSeriesForAndroidVIntES", envelope);

        SoapPrimitive result = (SoapPrimitive) envelope.getResponse();
```

Answer (score 3):

I know the answer comes really late, but hopefully someone else might benefit from it.
I have followed the following tutorial http://seesharpgears.blogspot.com.es/2010/10/ksoap-android-web-service-tutorial-with.html to send complex types and received the similar error.
The problem was caused by the default namespace as ksoap doesn't know how to map the objects.
Try to define your own namespace by setting it on the service, on the service interface and on the object that is being passed on the service method:

- decorate service with: [ServiceBehavior(Namespace = http://yournamespace.org/)]
- decorate service interface with:  [ServiceContract(Namespace =
  http://yournamespace.org/)]
- decorate your object with: [DataContract(Namespace = http://yournamespace.org/)]

Also adjust your client code in order to match the new namespace by replacing tempuri.org with your own: yournamespace.org.
For further details on how to eliminate the tempuri namespace please read the following post: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/endpoint/archive/2011/05/12/how-to-eliminate-tempuri-org-from-your-service-wsdl.aspx